# MySQL processes and connections

Tags: php, mysql, database, optimization, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpmyadmin built-in monitor tools to evaluate the usage of my MySQL db.
This graphed has raised my attention:

[image]

I assume the blue means connections, and the orange processes.

I'm trying to get a deep understanding of what this graph actually means, and act accordingly.

If I understand correctly, it seems as if I'm creating multiple connections per script (process).
What situations can cause such a behavior (in addition to simply calling mysql_connect more than once), and how much does this effect performance?

Comment: +1 for using a graph!

Comment: Are you using singleton structure to create/get database connection?

Comment: I'm using dependency injection design pattern. However, this graph makes me wonder if I have a bug (or not understanding it/db behavior  correctly).

Answer (score 6):

The blue line shows *recently opened* connections (i.e. opened since the last sample), while the orange one shows *currently opened* connections (at the time of sampling). The latter are processes **in MySQL** (the ones that show when you issue a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command to MySQL -- it really means *active connections*)

This means that most connections stay opened for less than your sampling period. This is a good thing.

I am unable to find official documention for this feature.

Comment: MySQL has a limit on max connections. Does this refer to the blue/orange line? (I would guess blue, but that means I'm over it)

Comment: @Noam It appears that the blue line is in fact the number of "new connections" (since the last sample, I guess). This is what I observe on my local machine: the line is at 1 all the time (the conection that PhpMyAdmin must be using to poll the data), even though I have several open connections in my console.

Comment: @Noam Sorry for wrong information, I must have messed with my tabs, or I was watching the wrong server. Please see my new edit.